# Paypal Test API Link could not open secure channel

Tags: asp.net, paypal, express-checkout

The Test API Link is not working in my program.

Please check the following screen shot.

[image]

When I type, the Test API URL ( https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp ) value in browser address bar, it return FAILURE value and error message, but I know why it was happen that I do not pass the credential values and other mandatory fields.

According to that logic, when I debug the link (Test API Link) in my program without credentials values, it is leading me to this exception instead of it returns FAILURE.

So I try with Live API ( https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp ) URL whether to make sure my program errors or not, but live API link give me FAILURE result.

And the test link was still working in this program last two days ago.

I am using .Net Framework 4.5.

Please tell me all the possible reasons why I was getting this error.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the endpoints are now updated to use TLS1.2, therefore you should be using SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 before the NVPAPICaller call.
i.e

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
NVPAPICaller PPCaller = new NVPAPICaller();
```

....

more info on the TLS updates:
https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1914&expand=true&locale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

PayPal sandbox has moved to TLS 1.2 protocol.
However after adding "System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;" in front of your call, this should resolve the TLS 1.2 issue.

Comment: Thank you Martien, When i report to paypal they reply the same as you say and now it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

When I report to Paypal about the issue as same post here, they reply the sanbox has upgraded to TLS1.2 and HTTP 1.1. For asp.net use "System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12" and the project need to run on .Net Framework 4.5. If it was under 4.5 we cannot call **Tls12**

the reference link is here

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US